# How to change background color in a text button in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

How should I change the background color of the text and icon at the same time in a text button in flutter????
I used flat button before but the "vs code " editor said its deprecated.

Comment: Add some code of what you have

Answer (score 1):

```
TextButton(
    child: Text('test'),
    style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red)),
    onPressed: () {},
),
```

Comment: You did not add icon at the button .The text color  can be changed but not the background color of icon

Answer (score 0):

```
        TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("test"),style: ButtonStyle(
        minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
            Size(80, 29)),
        padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(
            EdgeInsets.zero),
        backgroundColor:
        MaterialStateProperty.all(
            Color(0xFF3D7FFF))),)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: IT will only change the color of text written on the button but not  of the icon .Problem still there